# Array not saved - Swiftui

Tags: arrays, swiftui, model, local-storage, var

Another day, another issue... :-(
So, I have a form in which I add people, and the ADDING method works fine, stores data in my array "Storage" managed by datamanager file.
Now I've changed the textfields to make them editable, the procedure works fine, I can modify values and the interface layout updates itself.... BUT.
Every time I close the app, values are back to a pre-modified state, so it means that what I am missing, is the correct command to write the changed value in the array... and I am not able to do it.
Any help?

This is the view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct DetailView: View {
@ObservedObject var cliente : AppModel

@State var nameInEditMode = false
@State var isEditPresented = false
@State var isTestPressed = false


var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Informazioni")) {
                    HStack {
                        Group {
                                Section(header: Text("")) {
                                    if nameInEditMode {
                                        TextField("Name", text: $cliente.nome).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle()).font(.system(size: 14))
                                                .autocapitalization(.words)
                                                .disableAutocorrection(true)
                                                .frame(width: 200, alignment: .leading)
                                                .offset(x: -7, y: -1)
                                                } else {
                                                    Image(systemName: "person.fill").resizable().frame(width: 15, height: 15).offset(x: -15, y: 0).foregroundColor(.blue)
                                                    Text("\(cliente.nome)").font(.system(size: 15)).offset(x: -13, y: 0)}
                                }
                            }
                        
                        Spacer()
                        Button(action: {
                            self.nameInEditMode.toggle()
                            debugPrint(cliente.nome)
                            
                            
                            
                        }) {
                            Text(nameInEditMode ? "Fatto" : "Modifica").font(.system(size: 14)).fontWeight(.light)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                        }
                    }
```

So, after debug print of modified name (correct but last character not shown WHY??) there's the place to the "PUT IN THE ARRAY" command and I can't figure it out.

DataManager file:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class DataManager: ObservableObject {

static let shared = DataManager()

var storage : [AppModel] = [] {
    didSet {
        objectWillChange.send()
    }
}

typealias Storage = [AppModel]

var filePath : String = ""

init() { caricaDati() }

func caricaDati() {
    
    filePath = cartellaDocuments() + "/colorliteTests.plist"

    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {
    
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
            
            let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
            
            storage = try decoder.decode(Storage.self, from: data)
        } catch {
            
            debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        
    } else {

        let clienteDemo = AppModel(nome: "Nome Demo", cognome: "Nome Demo", indirizzo: "Via Demo 11", città: "Demo", telefono: "12345678", sphDx: "-0.50", cylDx: "-1.00", axDx: "130", sphSx: "-0.50", cylSx: "-0.50", axSx: "80", addizione: "+1.00", note: "", risultatoRG: "300")

        storage = [clienteDemo]
        salva()    
    }
}

func nuovoCliente(nome: String, cognome: String, Indirizzo: String, città: String, telefono: String, sphDx: String, cylDx: String, axDx: String, sphSx: String, cylSx: String, axSx: String, addizione: String, note: String, risultatoRG: String) {
    
        let nuovoCliente = AppModel(nome: nome, cognome: cognome, indirizzo: Indirizzo, città: città, telefono: telefono, sphDx: sphDx, cylDx: cylDx, axDx: axDx, sphSx: sphSx, cylSx: cylSx, axSx: axSx, addizione: addizione, note: note, risultatoRG: risultatoRG)
    
            storage.insert(nuovoCliente, at: 0)
    
            salva()
}

func modificaCliente(clienteID: UUID, nome: String, cognome: String, Indirizzo: String, città: String, telefono: String, sphDx: String, cylDx: String, axDx: String, sphSx: String, cylSx: String, axSx: String, addizione: String, note: String) {
    
    if let cliente = (storage.filter { $0.id.uuidString == clienteID.uuidString }).first {
        
        cliente.nome = nome
        cliente.cognome = cognome
        cliente.indirizzo = Indirizzo
        cliente.città = città
        cliente.telefono = telefono
        cliente.sphDx = sphDx
        cliente.sphSx = sphSx
        cliente.axDx = axDx
        cliente.sphSx = sphSx
        cliente.cylSx = cylSx
        cliente.axSx = axSx
        cliente.addizione = addizione
        cliente.note = note
        cliente.aggiornaUI()
            
        salva()
        }
    }

func salva() {
    
    let encoder = PropertyListEncoder()
    encoder.outputFormat = .xml 
   
    do {
       
        let data = try encoder.encode(storage)
       
        try data.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
    } catch {
       
        debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    
}

func cancella(index: Int) {
    guard storage.indices.contains(index) else { return }
    storage.remove(at: index)
    salva()
}
```

Model file:

```
 import SwiftUI
 import Combine


class AppModel: Codable, Identifiable, ObservableObject  {
    
    var id : UUID = UUID()
    var nome : String
    var cognome : String
    var indirizzo : String
    var città : String
    var telefono : String
    var sphDx : String = "0.00"
    var cylDx : String = "0.00"
    var axDx : String = "0"
    var addizione : String = "+0.00"
    var sphSx : String = "0.00"
    var cylSx : String = "0.00"
    var axSx : String = "0"
    var note: String
    var risultatoRG : String = "300"

init(nome: String, cognome: String, indirizzo: String, città: String, telefono: String, sphDx: String, cylDx: String, axDx: String, sphSx: String, cylSx : String, axSx: String, addizione: String, note :String, risultatoRG : String) {
        self.nome = nome
        self.cognome = cognome
        self.indirizzo = indirizzo
        self.città = città
        self.telefono = telefono
        self.sphDx = sphDx
        self.cylDx = cylDx
        self.axDx = axDx
        self.sphSx = sphSx
        self.cylSx = cylSx
        self.axSx = axSx
        self.addizione = addizione
        self.note = note
    self.risultatoRG = risultatoRG
    }
   
    func aggiornaUI() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }

}
```

AddView File:

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddView: View {
var dm : DataManager = DataManager.shared

var cliente : AppModel?

@Binding var dismissFlag : Bool

@State var nome : String = ""
@State var cognome : String = ""
@State var indirizzo : String = ""
@State var città : String = ""
@State var telefono : String = ""
@State var sphDx : String = ""
@State var cylDx : String = ""
@State var axDx : String = ""
@State var sphSx : String = ""
@State var cylSx : String = ""
@State var axSx : String = ""
@State var add : String = ""
@State var note: String = ""
```

DetailView File where I make the Edit:

```
import SwiftUI

struct DetailView: View {
var dm : DataManager = DataManager.shared
@ObservedObject var cliente : AppModel

@State var nameInEditMode = false
@State var isEditPresented = false
@State var isTestPressed = false


var body: some View {
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't comment yet, so I put it as an answer:

after **cliente.nome** is changed (which is already in the array) you just have to save –
either by calling **DataManager.salva()** directly from the button,
or by adding salva() to your **storage - didset {}** routine

Comment: Hi ChrisR, it's just what I did, but every time app restart, data is not saved...

Comment: suggestions:
1. does saving work otherwise?
2. is the salva() routine called? put a debugprint in it to check
3. is the changed value still there when you save?

Comment: I think I've found the problem,  the "insert" of a new contact is in the ADDView file, that call all the @state var for name, surname etc.
The edit process is in another View, called DetailView, and in that file there's no call for all the State vars so datas are not stored in the array. 
The fact is that now I have a Published var for my appModel var, and so if I put all the state var also in that DetailView, returns a red flag in the procedure.